# iPad Air - deleted photo appears over and over again and copies itself

Tags: ipad, photo-stream, camera-roll

The picture I've  received via Viber deleted already 40 times appears over and over again in camera roll and photo stream !

How do i delete?

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem :

1 open viber and find who send you this photo
2 delete the photo from the chat or the all conversation ( slide left + delete)
3 delete all copy of this photo in the gallery and from the deleted folder